# Perl XML::Compile::Schema Against MIcrosoft Windows Task Scheduler Schema

Tags: xml, perl

When I try to parse the [Microsoft windows Task Scheduler schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383609(v=vs.85).aspx), I get errors similar to:

> Argument "PT1M" isn't numeric in numeric ge (>=) at /Library/Perl/5.18/XML/Compile/Schema/BuiltInFacets.pm line 158

I used the following code to parse, which works when I try it against a simple, hand-written schema that uses duration and duration range elements. So I know the module works fine with the more complex Microsoft schema, and it must be in how I'm using it.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use XML::LibXML;
    use XML::Compile::Schema;
    use XML::Compile::Util qw/pack_type/;
    my $schema = XML::Compile::Schema->new( "task-scheduler-ms.xsd" );
    my $type   = pack_type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task', 'Task';
    my $elem   = pack_type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task', 'Task';
    $schema->printIndex;
    my $read   = $schema->compile(READER => $elem);
```

I suspect I'm not calling a required module sub to accommodate the more complex Microsoft schema, but I'm stumped at the moment and I don't see anything promising in the documentation to try next.

**Update 20160114**

simbabque correctly advised that I should use strict and warnings, I updated the sample code. As he suspected, it doesn't reveal anything, but it's best practice to follow.

Mark (the module author) suspects that the error messages are actually caused by a defect in the module, because durations are not currently a special case in the comparison code. He hadn't run across a minInclusive facet on a date element before. I'm trying to assemble a minimum XSD that uses minInclusive facet in a duration typed element to force the module to emit the same error message.

I confirm Mark's suspicion with the following sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::Compile::Schema;
use XML::Compile::Util qw/pack_type/;
my $schema = XML::Compile::Schema->new( "duration-range-example-2.xsd" );
my $type   = pack_type 'http://tempuri.org/durationExample', 'Duration';
my $elem   = pack_type 'http://tempuri.org/durationExample', 'Duration';
$schema->printIndex;
my $read   = $schema->compile(READER => $elem);
```

Using the following sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/durationExample">
  <xs:element name="Duration" default="PT10M" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
        <xs:minInclusive value="PT1M"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This produces the following output:

```
namespace: http://tempuri.org/durationExample
 filename: duration-range-example-2.xsd
  definitions of elements:
    Duration
Argument "PT1M" isn't numeric in numeric ge (>=) at /Library/Perl/5.18/XML/Compile/Schema/BuiltInFacets.pm line 158.
Argument "PT10M" isn't numeric in numeric ge (>=) at /Library/Perl/5.18/XML/Compile/Schema/BuiltInFacets.pm line 158.
```

I'll follow up with Mark on a fix if one is feasible, and report back here the end result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. Please make sure you always `use strict` and `use warnings` when asking or answering here, as that will help diagnose a lot of problems way easier, though it's probably not going to be obvious here.

Answer (score 1):

Mark issued a patch to BuiltInFacet.pm in [XML::Compile::Schema v1.52](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/XML-Compile-1.52/lib/XML/Compile/Schema.pod) as of 2016-01-15, and I confirmed the patch passes all my test cases; duration-typed elements with minInclusive and maxInclusive facets no longer cause the module to throw error messages. Many thanks and kudos to Mark.